# scala list covering to cortage

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have simple hierarchy

```
class A
case class B extends A
case class C extends A
case class D extends A
```

And need function

```
def f(list: List[A]) : (List[B], List[C], List[D]) = ???
```

I can collect B, C, D in muttable lists but I want write it in fucntional style

Answer (score 4):

Another variation

```
list.foldLeft((List.empty[B], List.empty[C],List.empty[D])) { case ((bs, cs, ds), a) =>
    a match {
      case x: B => (x :: bs, cs, ds)
      case x: C => (bs, x :: cs, ds)
      case x: D => (bs, cs, x :: ds)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What could be more functional than good old [`Foldable`](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Foldable.html) with couple of `std` library instances from [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) buddy.

```
import scalaz.syntax.foldable._
import scalaz.std.tuple._
import scalaz.std.list._

def f(list: List[A]) = list foldMap {
  case b: B => (List(b), Nil, Nil)
  case c: C => (Nil, List(c), Nil)
  case d: D => (Nil, Nil, List(d))
}
```

Note however that long lists are note quite good with appending elements, so a little bit more efficient implementation could be

```
import scalaz.syntax.foldable._
import scalaz.std.tuple._
import scalaz.std.vector._
import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.syntax.std.tuple._

def f(list: List[A]) = list foldMap {
  case b: B => (Vector(b), Vector( ), Vector( ))
  case c: C => (Vector( ), Vector(c), Vector( ))
  case d: D => (Vector( ), Vector( ), Vector(d))
} mapElements (_.toList, _.toList, _.toList)
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me it's quite optimal to use accumulator with lists in such case:

```
      case class Cortage(bs: List[B], cs: List[C], ds: List[D]) {
    def asCortage = (bs, cs, ds)
  }

  def f(list: List[A], acc: Cortage = Cortage(List(), List(), List())): (List[B], List[C], List[D])  =
    list match {
      case x :: t =>  f(t,
      x match {
        case x:B => acc.copy(bs = x :: acc.bs)
        case x:C => acc.copy(cs = x :: acc.cs)
        case x:D => acc.copy(ds = x :: acc.ds)
      })
      case Nil => acc.asCortage
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I can not comment answers, I provide my solution which 
preserves order and includes case for A.

```scala
def f(xs: List[A]): (List[B], List[C], List[D]) = {
  @tailrec
  def group(xs: List[A], bs: List[B], cs: List[C], ds: List[D]): (List[B], List[C], List[D]) = xs match {
    case Nil => (bs.reverse, cs.reverse, ds.reverse)
    case (b: B) :: t  => group(t, b :: bs, cs, ds)
    case (c: C) :: t  => group(t, bs, c :: cs, ds)
    case (d: D) :: t  => group(t, bs, cs, d :: ds)
    case _ :: t => group(t, bs, cs, ds)
  }

  group(xs, List(), List(), List())
}
```